# compare two element in a function using iterator in python

Tags: python, list, class, function, iterator

I am new in python and I have a small problem to understand and use an iterator in a class.

```
def findLargest(shapes):
"""
Returns a tuple containing the elements of ShapeSet with the
   largest area.
shapes: ShapeSet
"""
bestName = shapes.List[:]
for i in shapes.List:
    if i.cmp(i+1)== -1:
        bestName.remove(memo)
    if i.cmp(i+1)==1:
        bestName.remove(i)
for element in bestName:
    stringout=''
    stringout= stringout + 'Element ' + str(element.name) + ' with an area of ' + str(element.area()) + ', '
return stringout
```

So basically, I want to compare the area of a list of element and get a tuple of elements with the biggest area. My problem is to compare my element "i" to the element "i+1". I don't know how to call it. To iterate I define a method **iter** and next() in order to iterate over the shapes.List

Someone could help me or maybe tell me what would be the good way to implement this function.

Thanks

full code bellow

---

```
    from string import *

    class Shape(object):
def area(self):
    raise AttributeException("Subclasses should override this method.")

def cmp(self, other):
    if type(other) != Shape and type(other) !=Square and type(other) !=Triangle and type(other) !=Circle:
        return 'Not a shape!'
    if self.area > other.area:
        return 1
    if self.area == other.area:
        return 0
    if self.area < other.area:
        return -1

    class Square(Shape):
def __init__(self, h, name):
    """
    h: length of side of the square
    """
    self.side = float(h)
    self.name = name
def area(self):
    """
    Returns area of the square
    """
    return self.side**2

def __str__(self):
    return 'Square with side ' + str(self.side)

def __eq__(self, other):
    """
    Two squares are equal if they have the same dimension.
    other: object to check for equality
    """
    return type(other) == Square and self.side == other.side

    class Circle(Shape):
def __init__(self, radius, name):
    """
    radius: radius of the circle
    """
    self.radius = float(radius)
    self.name = name

def area(self):
    """
    Returns approximate area of the circle
    """
    return 3.14159*(self.radius**2)
def __str__(self):
    return 'Circle with radius ' + str(self.radius)
def __eq__(self, other):
    """
    Two circles are equal if they have the same radius.
    other: object to check for equality
    """
    return type(other) == Circle and self.radius == other.radius

   # Problem 1: Create the Triangle class

    class Triangle(Shape):
def __init__(self, base, height, name):
    self.base= float(base)
    self.height=float(height)
    self.name = name

def area (self):
    area=float(self.base*self.height)/2
    return area

def __str__(self):
    return 'Triangle with a base ' + str(self.base) +' and height ' + str(self.height)

def __eq__ (self, other):
    return type(other)==Triangle and self.base == other.base and self.height == other.height

    #Problem 2: Create the ShapeSet class

    class ShapeSet:
def __init__(self):
    """
    Initialize any needed variables
    """
    self.List = []
    self.index=0

def addShape(self, sh):
    """
    Add shape sh to the set; no two shapes in the set may be
    identical
    sh: shape to be added
    """
    if self==[]:
        self.List.append(sh)
    else:
        for shape in self.List:
            if shape == sh:
                return 'This shape already exist'
            if shape.area == sh.area and type(shape) == type(sh):
                return 'This shape already exist'
        self.List.append(sh)

def __iter__(self):
    """
    Return an iterator that allows you to iterate over the set of
    shapes, one shape at a time
    """
    return self

def next():
    if self.index>len(self.List-1):
        StopIteration
    else:
        self.index+=1
        return self.List[self.index-1]


def __str__(self):
    """
    Return the string representation for a set, which consists of
    the string representation of each shape, categorized by type
    (circles, then squares, then triangles)
    """
    triangleList=[]
    squareList=[]
    circleList=[]
    if self.List == []:
        return 'The set is empty'
    else:
        for element in self.List:
            if type(element)==Triangle:
                triangleList.append(element.name)
            elif type(element)==Square:
                squareList.append(element.name)
            elif type(element)==Circle:
                circleList.append(element.name)
        return 'circles: %s, square: %s, triangle: %s' % (circleList, squareList, triangleList)
```

---

Comment: ShapeSet should subclass list (or UserList), it would make it much simpler.

Comment: What's more, since Square, Triangle etc. subclass `Shape`, you can replace the line with `if type(other)...` with `assert isinstance(other, Shape)`. In `__cmp__` you are comparing `area` (which a function) instead of `area()` (which is the result of this function.

Answer (score 2):

In your class, implement **[__cmp__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)** instead of cmp, then you can use Python builtins, such as:

```
bestName = max(shapes.List)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I guess its not an answer to his question, but it seems like a better solution to his problem =)

Comment: This is absolutely the best way to solve this problem, assuming he doesn't plan on using __cmp__ for something else

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pairwise` [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the [itertools module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

for previous, current in pairwise(shapes.List):
    # etc
```

Alternatively you could first find the maximum area:

```
max_area = max(shapes, lambda s: s.area())
```

Then use this to find all the elements with that area:

```
result = [s for s in shapes if s.area() == max_area]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class shape():
    def __init__(self,side_length):
        self.side_length=side_length
    def area(self):
        return self.side_length*self.side_length

shape_list=[shape(i) for i in [1,6,3,12,9]]
import heapq
largest_3=heapq.nlargest(3,shape_list,key=shape.area)

for shape in largest_3:
    print shape.side_length

12
9
6
```